# How do I use specific string from an array for if else?

Tags: javascript

So im trying to create a script which creates an array and it interchanges it with numbers, if its 2 minus it to 1 and print it if its 1 print it, heres my code
edit: my question wasnt really stated, im trying to get a specific string and make it print so if it is 2 it minus to 1, I dont want string 2(B) i want string 1(A)

```js
//array
var link = new Array("A", "B");
//a floor function aswell as a Math.random to get a specific,
var link = link[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];
//test code
console.log(link)
//first part of if statement, if link is equal to 2 than print it.
if(link == 2)[console.log(link)];
```

Comment: I do not understand the goal of the function, can you clarify please?

Comment: @ptts If your talking about math.random and math.floor Its to get a random string from the array,

Comment: @ptts If not im only want A

Comment: The entire first paragraph/sentence is mystifying. The sample code is equally perplexing. It looks like it starts out with an attempt at random-choice-from-set, and then... I have no idea. I think OP is throwing away the data they need by re-defining `link`.

Comment: @Tom Its been a while and I just got back into coding but yeah I think that was what i was trying to do, and I also have no idea why my sentence structure was that bad since it wasnt that long and im normally great a writing. "Re write" Im trying to create a script which makes an array, This array adds numerical data to A/B A being 1 B being 2, I then wanted it always to print B,

Comment: @JoshuaSearles Please rewrite the question with more clarification. Firstly  `You're trying to make a script which makes an array! From what?` Secondly `The array maps A -> 1 and B -> 2` and Lastly `It always prints "B"`. If you want it to always print `B` then why not just use `console.log("B")`?